# Appcelerator - Android Picker not retaining selected value

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Consider the following code below:

```
function doClick(e) {
    win.open();
}

var picker = null;
var backBtn = null;
var selectedIdx = 0;

$.index.open();

var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    exitOnClose : false,
    navBarHidden : true
});

win.addEventListener("open", function() {

    if(null != picker) {
        //picker.setSelectedRow(0, selectedIdx, false);
        return;
    }

    picker = Titanium.UI.createPicker({
        width : "75%",
        height : "50dip",
        selectionIndicator : true
    });

    picker.addEventListener("change", function(id) {
        selectedIdx = id.rowIndex;
    });

    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({
            title : i,
            color : "black"
        }));
    }

    selectedIdx = 0;

    picker.add(arr);

    backBtn = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        bottom : "10dip",
        title : "Close"
    });
    backBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        win.close();
    });

    win.add(picker);
    win.add(backBtn);
});
```

If the above code is executed with SDK 5.2.0.GA or 5.2.2.GA, then you will see that the picker value is not being retained. After ever open/close of the window, even if we reuse the old picker object. But, if you uncomment the setSelectedRow (hack code I would say), then it behaves as required.

Anyone faced such issue or is aware of a proper solution or root cause for it.

Comment: I have created a JIRA for this, in-case any one is interested and would like to watch it.
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3592

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is expected behavior. The picker is attached to a window and on Android starting with Release 3.2.0, all the windows are heavyweight. A heavyweight window is associated with a new Android Activity. So when the window is closed the activity is closed and so will be the picker. It that case the picker is not supposed retain its selected value. You can try using lightweight window in this case.

Prior to Release Titanium 3.2.0 in Android, Titanium windows can be heavyweight or lightweight:

- A heavyweight window is associated with a new Android Activity.
- A lightweight window is a fullscreen view, and runs in the current Android Activity.

If you still want the old behavior, you can enable the ti.android.useLegacyWindow property in the tiapp.xml:

```
<property name="ti.android.useLegacyWindow" type="bool">true</property>
```

[Documentation Link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window)

Comment: As per the JIRA ticket too, it seems to be the correct behavior. The developer needs to manually revert back the old selected value to reflect the change. Hence marking this as an answer, though the legacyWindow property is not required for this.

Answer (score 1):

I use `Ti.UI.Picker` for date/times. And in that case you need to set the `value` property to tell the picker what value is selected. I guess you need the same with other types of picker, like:

```
picker = Titanium.UI.createPicker({
        width : "75%",
        height : "50dip",
        selectionIndicator : true,
        value : '0'
    });
```

/John